# How can server request to retrieve data from client

Tags: php

How do I make the server retrieve data from the client python program to the server php
 program 
I want to know how the server requests to retrieve data from the client program

Comment: Use related docs

Comment: Anything other than related docs

Comment: Check the related docs or google, you should find plenty of resources

Answer (score 0):

A server can not ask a client for data. Else your client would also be a server.

So instead in such situations, the client regularily connects to the server and pushes the data the server needs, or asks the server, what the server wants to do next. A more higly advanced technique would be that the client opens a connection to the server and keeps it open for as long as possible, so the server can send the answer/request at any time it needs to.
See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology